# ImageResizer generate wrong width for the image

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I let users upload a banner with a minimum width of 400px. This image will then get a wide of 1110px. 
I try to upload images with the following sizes: 960x390, 410x410, 784x250.
When i upload 784x250, the image get the same size 784x250 not the width, 1110px.

I use this:

```
        int Height;
        using (var Bmp = new Bitmap(str))
        {
            if (Bmp.Width < 400)
            {
                throw;
            }
            if (Bmp.Height < 150)
            {
                throw;
            }
            Height = Bmp.Height;
        }

        if (Height > 300)
        {
            Height = 300;
        }

        str.Position = 0;
        var ImageData = str.StreamToByteArray();

        var Settings = "width=1110;height="+ Height + ";format=jpg;mode=crop;"

        var Setting = new ResizeSettings(Settings);
        using (var Out = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var In = new MemoryStream(ImageData))
            {
                In.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var I = new ImageJob(In, Out, Setting)
                {
                    CreateParentDirectory = false
                };
                I.Build();
            }

            Out.Position = 0;

            // Upload to blob
        }
```

(str contains a stream with the image)

I want the image to be 1110px wide and max 300px high.
Whats wrong?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this is the culprit: "mode=crop;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageResizer does not upscale images unless you specifically ask for it via `scale=both` or `scale=canvas`. Upscaling is typically undesired.

Also, you can pass the stream directly to ImageJob and simplify your code significantly.

```
str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var Out = new MemoryStream(8096);
new ImageJob(str, Out, new Instructions("width=1110;height="+ Height + ";format=jpg;mode=crop;scale=both")).Build();
Out.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other sizes you tested each have a `Bmp.Height > 300` which means the image requires to be cropped.
However when using an image size 784x250, the image doesn't require to be cropped. So you'll never re-size the image.

Assuming you wish to keep the image proportionally correct, you should first re-size the image to match the wanted width and afterwards crop the exceeding height if necessary.

```
var image = new Bitmap(str);

var ratio = (double)1110 / image.Width;

var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
var bmp = new Bitmap(newImage);

if(bmp.Height > 300){
//Resize again using crop, like you did in your original code.
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Bitmap and Graphics instances are not garbage collected as they appear as 1kb (instead of 90mb) to the .NET GC. Thus this code, if called a few dozen times sequentially, will crash the server. Also, DrawImage uses a process-wide lock (unlike ImageResizer's FastScaling engine), so if there are concurrent requests, those large blocks of memory will be held for a very, very long time.